# javaScript Array, cant loop over an Array for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-query

console.log(usersQuery.data); // this is working fine and log and array of users

console.log(usersQuery.data[1]); // this is making me go crazy it is returning undefined

everything else is working as intended
here is my Code

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import App from "./App";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
      cacheTime: Infinity,
    },
  },
});

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
    <ReactQueryDevtools />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import getUsers from "./GetUsers";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
function App() {
  const usersQuery = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["initUsers"],
    queryFn: () => getUsers(),
  });
  if (usersQuery.isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (usersQuery.isError) return <p>something went wrong</p>;
  if (usersQuery.isFetched) {

// The first log is working fine 

      console.log(usersQuery.data);
      console.log(usersQuery.data[1]);

// The second log waisted 3 hours of my life and I'am tired 


    return (
      <ul>
        <li>hi</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

getUsers.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";

function getUsers() {
  const users = [];
  axios
    .get("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=5&response_type=json")
    .then((x) => x.data.map((user) => users.push(user)))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  return users;
}

export default getUsers;
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4Ii.png)

I am learning ReactQuery and axios, and i was just playing around,then i got stuck which is something i kind of got used to but i always find a way but this time i couldn't.

Tried usersQuery.data.map method, tried forEeach and then tried to access one user and i got undefined.
please help !
Thank you in advance

Comment: Console logs may be updated after async processes complete. Stringify it instead. But you’re missing some JS async basics as well.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, if I may take some more of your time sir,
 i tried doing another log like this :

      console.log(usersQuery.data); // this was fine 
      console.log(usersQuery.data[0]); // undefined 
      console.log(usersQuery.data); // this was fine 

so the array is there and I can see its contents but accessing it values with js is not working as intended, I just want to know what is the logic behind this ?

Comment: Console logs may be updated after async processes complete. Stringify it instead. But you’re missing some JS async basics as well.